# If statement inside repeat until loop

Tags: pascal, swingame

I'm creating a toggle button using the SwinGame library. Right now I'm struggling with actually making it toggle. That bit looks like this:

```
var
  clr: Color;
  clicked: Boolean;
  boolcheck: String;
begin
    OpenGraphicsWindow('Toggle button test', windowsWidth, windowsHeight); 
    clr := ColorWhite;
    clicked := true;
    boolcheck := 'true';
    repeat 
        ClearScreen(clr);
        ProcessEvents();
        //Play button and Pause button
        if (ButtonClicked(buttonX-buttonRadius, buttonY-buttonRadius, buttonRadius*2, buttonRadius*2) = true) and (clicked = true) then 
            begin
                clr := ColorRed;
                clicked := false;
                boolcheck := 'false';
                DrawAButton();
            end
        else if (ButtonClicked(buttonX-buttonRadius, buttonY-buttonRadius, buttonRadius*2, buttonRadius*2) = true) and (clicked = false) then
            begin
                clr := ColorBlue;
                clicked := true;
                boolcheck := 'true';
                DrawADifferentButton();
            end;
        DrawText(echo, ColorBlack, 'arial.ttf', 14, 55, 55);
        RefreshScreen();
    until WindowCloseRequested();
end;
```

Basically I intended to make it so if the user clicks on this area of the window via `ButtonClicked()` (a SwinGame function), and the clicked variable is false, then the background color will be red, if not then blue. But for some reason I could only change it to red, blue did not appear at all. I did some troubleshooting by creating a `boolcheck` variable and I saw the variable was constantly being put at true, I did see it change to false for a fraction of a second then back to true....But I did not put the `clicked` variable initial definition inside the loop, so why isn't it staying false?

EDIT: Here's the definition to the `ButtonClicked` function

```
function ButtonClicked(posX, posY: Single; w, h: Integer): Boolean; 
var 
    x, y: Single;
begin 
    x := MouseX(); 
    y := MouseY();
    result := false;

    if MouseClicked(LeftButton) then 
    begin 
        if (x >= posX) and (x <= w + posX) and (y >= posY) and (y <= h + posY) then 
        begin 
            result := true; 
        end; 
    end; 
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in `ButtonClicked`? At what point does the state of the button per `ButtonClicked` get reset? As an aside, you can simplify the look and flow of your logic quite a bit. `if foo = true then...` is the same as simply `if foo then` since `foo` is a boolean. Likewise, `if foo = false then` is the same as `if not foo then`. Finally `if A and B then X else if A and not B then Y` can be written `if A then if B then X else Y`. Where A and B are boolean expressions, and X and Y are code blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. About the function...I don't think I get what you mean when you said at what state does it get reset....I've added the function `ButtonClicked` in. Hopefully that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @lurker 's suggestion, I've solved it. After spending some time thinking about @lurker 's suggestion, I realized that once the procedure gets reset, it'll start off with `clicked` being at 0 again. So what I had to do, was making the the `ButtonClicked` check a function that returns `1` or `0`, or `true` or `false` into clicked in `Main()`. That way `clicked` will always be updated, and the procedure won't be reset with clicked being at 0 all the time.

```
function Toggle(clicked): Integer;
if ButtonClicked(buttonX-buttonRadius, buttonY-buttonRadius, buttonRadius*2, buttonRadius*2) then 
    if (clicked := true) then
        begin
            clr := ColorRed;
            result := false;
            DrawAButton();
        end
else
    begin
        clr := ColorBlue;
        result := true;
        DrawADifferentButton();
end;

then in `Main()` I would call it as follow:
//Stuffs
begin
    clicked := true;
    repeat
        clicked := Toggle(clicked);
    //Other stuffs
```

Comment: ` if (clicked := true) then` ==> `if clicked then`. (`:=` is an error here anyway). You also don't need a function `Toggle`. Just `clicked := not clicked;`.